# HTML - Dynamically created input labels, for attribute

Tags: javascript, html, label

Is there a way to link a label to an input without using the input's id ?

I'm creating/deleting input / label couples dynamically and i would like not to have to generate unique IDs for the for attribute. Can this be done using classes or something else ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Since you would like not to generate unique IDs, I think you just put label and input together into a parent div

Comment: @TelvinNguyen — No. "Being in the same div" does not associate a label with a form control.

Answer (score 4):

Yes place the input inside the label

```
<label><input type="text" name="myName" /> First name</label>
```

Have a look here - [Possible to associate label with checkbox without using "for=id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537621/possible-to-associate-label-with-checkbox-without-using-for-id/8537641#8537641)

> When an `<input>` is inside a `<label>`, the connection between them is
>   implicit.

[HTML4 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1)

Comment: actually the for attribute was used for screen readers to disabled persons, so not useful for accessibility to write without for attribute

Comment: Awesome, this is a good tactic