# multiple instances, same ids

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new in Html/Css/Js, so this might be a dummy question. I'm trying to make a component A (a container who resizes itself when you press it) in order to use it in other component B with ng-include (I want to have in component B some instances of the component A).

I've read about it and I'm using the trick with the checkbox (http://jsfiddle.net/nMNJE/)

Html:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="button">
  <label class="ani" for="button"></label>
```

CSS:

```
    input{
    display:none;
    }
    .ani
    {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        border: solid thin black;
        transition:width 2s;
       -moz-transition:width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
       -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -o-transition:width 2s; /* Opera */
        display:block;
   }
   input:checked + .ani{width:300px;}
```

When I include this component A with ng-include=" 'file.html' " in my B component,  I have problems because the instances have the same id and when I press on the second container, the first one resizes (doesn't matter on which container I press, because only the first will resize). So, the main question is: How can I make those instances  have their own id ?

Thanks,

Later edit:

For the inclusion part I use

```
<div ng-include="'componentA.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Ids are used for unique elements. If an element should be included more than one you have to use classes. You could wrap your ng-include with an id so you can select the right button

Comment: don't use same id instead of it use class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to associate label with checkbox without using "for=id"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537621/possible-to-associate-label-with-checkbox-without-using-for-id)

Comment: yet another way - try use unique id for label, and class for css

Comment: can you provide sample how you try use it with your angular?

Comment: this file `componentA.html` contain only two lines `<input type="checkbox" id="button">
  <label class="ani" for="button"></label>`?

Comment: yet another variant  - custom directive instead ng-include

Comment: I have the same things like here (http://jsfiddle.net/nMNJE/)

Comment: nope - in fiddle you have working sample, but you problem is how you use it with angular, so sample should be with angular, that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead `ng-include` you can just create a custom directive, and also generate unique id for input. Something like this

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {})
  .directive('myComponent', function() {
    var count = 0;
    return {
      scope: true, //create isolated scope
      template: '<input type="checkbox" id="button{{::num}}"> \
                 <label class="ani" for="button{{::num}}"></label>',//set template for directive
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.num = ++count; //add unique suffix
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
    input {
      display: none;
    }
    .ani {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: solid thin black;
      transition: width 2s;
      -moz-transition: width 2s;
      /* Firefox 4 */
      -webkit-transition: width 2s;
      /* Safari and Chrome */
      -o-transition: width 2s;
      /* Opera */
      display: block;
    }
    input:checked + .ani {
      width: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  1
  <div my-component></div>
  2
  <div my-component></div>
  3
  <div my-component></div>
  4
  <div my-component></div>
  5
  <div my-component></div>
  6
  <div my-component></div>

</div>
```

**Sidenote:** in css i think better use class instead hide any input

**Update:** instead `template` you can use `templateUrl` and pass url to you file like `componentA.html`

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been given already in the comments, but it is important enough to express it in an answer. Id's of DOM elements should be unique.

So your question title has the problem already in it, it should be:

**multiple instances, different ids**

Read more [here at mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) or [here at WC3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) on `id` tag on your html elements and that they have to be unique.

You need to make sure you don't duplicate id's and will have to use something else to find your elements. Best would be finding them by `className`:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
```