# Label associated with checkbox does not work when checkbox moved inside label

Tags: html, css

[MDN - Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) says:

> A `<label>` can be associated with a control either by placing the control element inside the  element, or by using the `for` attribute.

I was checking a demo for [Animated Checkbox with CSS3 Powered Animation](http://www.cssscript.com/animated-checkbox-with-css3-powered-animation/). I tired to make it as label with input element inside it, based on [Possible to associate label with checkbox without using "for=id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537621/possible-to-associate-label-with-checkbox-without-using-for-id).

When I made the change, the checkbox is not working. Why is it not working after this change and how to fix this?

**Working**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLPQoy

**Not Working**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjWodj

Note: I cannot use "For" attribute in label since the input elements will be dynamically added in my actual HTML page.

**HTML**

```
<div class="myDiv" style="padding:20px 0 20px 20px;">
<input type="checkbox" id="cbtest" />
<label for="cbtest" class="check-box"></label> 
</div>
```

Comment: your css rules are not updated in the not working. Label is the parent of .checkbox. But you are targeting like this input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox works just fine, as you can see if you make it visible (*it currently has `display:none`*).

The problem is that your CSS expects it to be outside so it can style the `.check-box` element when using `input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box`.

To fix this you should add another element after the checkbox and add the `check-box` class to that instead of the label.

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span class="check-box">
</label>
```

Updated codepen at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjWopx

Comment: Interesting. It works. I am trying to understand the logic of adding a span to fix this. Yes, I see that it meets the CSS expectation now. What I am not able to understand is how the `for` attribute was meeting the same expectation.

Comment: @Lijo it wasn't the `for`. In the css the `input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check-box` means that `.check-box` must be the next element after a `:checked` input, and that is how your html was in that example (*the `label` with the `.check-box` class was the next element of the input*). In the updated code we just fixed that mismatch by adding another element to be styled instead of the label.