# Ruby on Rails, formtastic gives different HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I have this template:

```
- f.inputs do
= user.input :is_vip?, :as => :boolean, :label=>'VIP'
= f.input :test, :as => :boolean, :required => false, :label => "This is TEST company"
= f.input :multi_destination, :as => :boolean, :required => false, :label => "Multi destination"
```

It's fully working thing. But the code that the browser receive is different in my localhost and in stage server. I don't know where to dig.
CSSes are exactly the same, sources are same, everything is the same.

Comment: Can you show us the "code that the browser receive" in both cases?

Comment: Sure : http://pastebin.com/XX9p8g8g

Comment: On localhost there is INPUT inside of LABEL and on stage there's two separate tags: input and label

Comment: Are both machines running the same version of Rails/other gems?

Comment: there's one Gemfile for both machines, versions are the same, I've checked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formtastic, by default, uses a method named `label_with_nested_checkbox` for rendering [boolean input](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic/inputs/boolean_input.rb#L38) fields. That method renders the checkbox inside the label - like you are getting in localhost.

Formtastic doesn't have any "default way" to "take the input field out of the label" (his author confirmed this to me on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720443/html-correct-way-of-coding-a-checkbox-with-a-label)) It must have been patched somehow to do that. Here're some possible places to look:

- Check inside the `apps/inputs` directory, if there is any. That's the "standard" place where someone can modify Formtastic plugins
- Check the `config/initializers` directory. To see if there is any Formtastic monkeypatching there.
- Check the `vendors` directory.
- Finally, even if the gem versions are the same, some could (grasp!) have changed the code of the gem itself in the server. I certainly hope they nave not. But anyway, uninstalling and reinstalling the gem, and maybe rebooting the server, should check that one out.